# Convert Array to Array of Arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this one:

```
array = ['john', 'jennifer', 'kristen', 'ted']
```

I would like to convert it to an array of arrays of k elements.
For example, if k = 2 the result should be:

```
[['john', 'jennifer'], ['kristen', 'ted']]
```

Is it possible to do so in one line?

Comment: This is covered in the [documentation for Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html). It's a really good habit to read through a language's documentation a couple times to become familiar with what's available. Each time through you'll learn more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) might help:

```
array.each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [["john", "jennifer"], ["kristen", "ted"]]
```

Comment: @Stefan, thank you - I need to learn to link to the API docs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create two arrays from one with a predicate (an expression which evaluates to either true or false), I would recommend [`partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)

```
array.partition{ |name| name[0] == 'j' }
#=> [["john", "jennifer"], ["kristen", "ted"]]
```